# transform string into column name

Tags: r

I have a function that does some calculations based on given model, data matrix and column name.

However I'm having some difficulty in understanding how can I pass information regarding the column name. I've tried:

```
var=as.name("IR2")
summary(mat$var)
```

But it does not work. Is it possible to do what I want? Thanks

Code to test:

```
mat <- matrix(rnorm(20), ncol=2, nrow=10)
colnames(mat) <- c("fy","IR2")
```

Comment: To find that duplicate all I did was type [r] followed vby your question title in the SO search box and it was the second hit ... after yours, of course. Please do some searching before posting questions. (I think it's also in the R-FAQ.)

Comment: I don't think they are the same.

Comment: I'm willing to listen to reasoned argument, but not just "I don't think so". In your case it should have been `summary(mat[[var]])`. Just because that construction of `[[` is used inside `summary` doesn't make it "different". The might even be 50 or 100 such questions on how using "$" doesn't work whereas using either `[` or `[[` with an unquoted symbol will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the column name is unknown before hand, you can call it by the following

```
mat[, "columnName"]
```

In your case, if you want to work only on the "fy" column, you can pass in that column name to your function and call it as above.

You would essentially be calling

```
mat[,"fy"]
```

For example, say we want to write a function that takes the matrix and column name, and computes the mean over the given column (and we want to make it from scratch because this is an example)

```
#mat is evaluated to be the following
 mat
 #          fy        IR2
 #[1,]  1.0355858 -0.1065325
 #[2,]  1.0415242 -0.7736924
 #[3,] -0.7607343 -1.6289547
 #[4,]  0.6743018 -0.4028445
 #[5,]  1.2324244  0.4847683
 #[6,]  0.2128944  1.1584937
 #[7,]  0.9460752 -1.6287894
 #[8,]  0.7093235  1.5833613
 #[9,]  0.3015283  0.3296974
 #[10,]  0.2002134  1.7815022

 mat[,"fy"]
 #this returns a vector, the column fy
 #[1]  1.0355858  1.0415242 -0.7607343  0.6743018  1.2324244  0.2128944
 #[7]  0.9460752  0.7093235  0.3015283  0.2002134

 colMean<-function(mat, columnName){
      mean(mat[,columnName])
}

colMean(mat, "fy")
#[1] 0.5593137
```

The $ won't work in this case as mat$var is looking for the column name "var" in mat, which doesn't exist.  Columns can also be subsetted as I show above, within single brackets by name.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to just name the columns using dimnames?

```
mat <- matrix(rnorm(20), ncol=2, nrow=10, dimnames= list(c(1:10), c("fy","IR2")))
```

dimnames contains a list of length 2 - the first element containing rownames, the second element the column names.

```
           fy         IR2
1   1.5718232  2.18202170
2  -1.4817695  1.33032923
3  -1.2346067 -1.30057189
4   1.0391464  1.27644013
5  -1.0915758 -0.24596097
6  -1.2552700  1.96342065
7  -0.4298826 -0.09694546
8   1.7375874  1.44590566
9   0.2504768  0.19940885
10  0.3293833 -0.88001511
```